# eMachines Broadcom wireless can't connect in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, broadcom

I have a eMachines netbook M350. It came with Windows 7 Starter installed.  Recently, I reinstalled a fresh copy of Win 7 Ultimate, downloaded the wireless drivers from the manufacturer's page, and now I can't connect to any wireless network when the netbook is disconnected from AC power.

Sometimes, the wireless works fine after a reboot, but it's not always the case. Usually, it stays connected for 2-3 minutes, then it disconnects from the network.

Now, I don't think it's a hardware issue, because I booted it with Ubuntu on a USB drive and it works just fine, connected to AC power or not.

On the other hand, now I can't restore the netbook to the default installation, because when I reboot the computer it doesn't show me any option to do so.  Does anyone knows how can I restore the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do anyone knows how can I restore the system?

When you upgraded to Ultimate it broke the factory restore function.

If the factory restore partition is still there you can use Disk management to mark the restore partition as "Active" then reboot, hopefully it will boot into the restore partition and allow you to restore it back to starter edition. Otherwise you would have to order recovery media from E Machines.

Comment: Yes, the partition is still there... i'm going to try that option, and post back the results!

Comment: Thanks! I was able to restore the partition, the original drivers works perfectly. So, I guess no win7 ultimate for me :(

Comment: Glad you got it restored. Something you can try, back up the drivers to an external drive using doubledriver software, Install Ultimate and use DD to restore the drivers, maybe it will work then....http://www.boozet.org/dd.htm

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a strange problem, you might want to try disabling the power saving feature in Windows for the adapter. You can find it under advanced power settings after right clicking the battery icon and opening power options:
[image]

That is the only thing I can think of that would effect it only when using battery.

Comment: Hi Kyle, I thought of that too, and turned off the power saving feature, but no effect :(